# when is rollup summary field calculated if there is insert and update in same transaction?

Tags: roll-up-summary

If My master record has one child record and I am updating a child record and making is_Active field on it false and then creating a new record which has is_Active = true in the same transanction will and i have a rollupsummary . when will it be calculated?

Answer (score 0):

It will be calculated twice, once for the update, and again for the insert. This will happen sometime after the after update/after insert trigger (see [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)).